# Jquery - collapsible Slider

Tags: jquery, background, slider, slideshow

I'm trying to combine the script from the following fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/1/ ,with a jquery background slider. The result i'm aiming for is that you can see part of the image in the collapsed state and when you active it the rest of the image becomes visible.

So far all the scripts i've tried negate the collapse functionality.

I really hope someone can help me out.

Thanks!